# Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in $D(0,r)$ and $|f(z)| \leq |z|, \forall z \in D(0,r).$ Is it true that $f^{(n)}(0)=0, \forall n =1,2,... \ ?$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in $D(0,r)$ and $|f(z)| \leq |z|, \forall z \in D(0,r).$ Is it true that $f^{(n)}(0)=0, \forall n =1,2,... \ ?$

May I verify if my proof is correct or wrong? Thank you.

Let $C$ be any positively oriented circle of radius $r_o$ that is contained in $D(0,r).$

Then, $\left|f^{(n)}(0)\right| =\left|\begin{align}\dfrac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{C}  \dfrac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz\end{align}\right| \leq$ $ \begin{align} \dfrac{n!}{2\pi }\int_{C} \dfrac{1}{|z|^{n}}\end{align}dz=$ $ \begin{align} \dfrac{n!}{2\pi r_o^n}\int^{2\pi}_{0}ir_oe^{i\theta}d\theta\end{align}=0.$

Comment: No. First, consider $f(z) = z$. That satisfies the inequality, but $f'(0) \neq 0$. Then, $dz$ is not real-valued, so an inequality $a \leqslant \int_C g(z)\,dz$ with a real-valued $g$ does in general not make sense (the value of the integral is generally not real). The correct inequality is $$\lvert f^{(n)}(0)\rvert \leqslant \frac{n!}{2\pi} \int_C \frac{\lvert dz\rvert}{\lvert z\rvert^n},$$ and that gives you $\lvert f^{(n)}(0)\rvert \leqslant \frac{n!}{r^{n-1}}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer that's pretty much a full answer...

Comment: I guess that's true, @NajibIdrissi. Converting it.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks for the great advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's incorrect. First, consider $f(z) = z$. That satisfies the inequality, but $f'(0) \neq 0$.

Then, $dz$ is not real-valued, so an inequality $a \leqslant \int_C g(z)\,dz$ with a real-valued $g$ does in general not make sense (the value of the integral is generally not real). The correct inequality is

$$\lvert f^{(n)}(0)\rvert \leqslant \frac{n!}{2\pi} \int_C \frac{\lvert dz\rvert}{\lvert z\rvert^n},$$

with the arc-length measure $\lvert dz\rvert$, that, for a parametrisation $\gamma$ of the curve becomes $\lvert\gamma'(t)\rvert\,dt$, and that gives you the estimate $\lvert f^{(n)}(0)\rvert \leqslant \frac{n!}{r^{n-1}}$.

The function $f(z) = r^{1-n}z^n$ shows that the estimate is sharp, for all $n$ there is a function such that $\lvert f^{(n)}(0)\rvert$ attains the bound.